# dialog windows with two displays

Tags: windows

I have two displays and I'd like to move Blender to the secondary display and not the main one, because of resolution stuff (main display is a laptop display scaled 125% and it kinda leaves less room for a workspace).

When I do this, any modal/dialog window is still opened on main display and also with random size every time, resulting in a very ugly view sometimes:

[image]

It bothers me a lot and I keep wondering is there a way to somehow fix the size of the modal window? Is it possible to set it to "800x600"?

Thanks.